# SAS . Are variables set to missing at every iteration of a data step?

Tags: sas

I always thought that the variables are set to missing for every iteration of the data step . However, in the following code, it looks like the value that the variable gets at the very beginning retains. I can't understand why this happens ?

```
data one;
input x $ y;
datalines;
a 10
a 13
a 14
b 9
;
run;

data two;
input z;
datalines;
45
;
run;

data test;
if _n_ = 1 then set two; /* when _n_=2 the PDV assigns missing values, right ? */
set one;
run;
proc print;
run;
```

The outcome is

```
   z      x     y  
   45     a    10
   45     a    13
   45     a    14
   45     b     9
```

I was expecting to get this

```
   z      x     y  
   45     a    10
   .      a    13
   .      a    14
   .      b     9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SAS does **not** reset the values in PDV for - SET, MERGE, MODIFY, or UPDATE statements. Since you are using SET statement so SAS is not resetting it.

```
if _n_ = 1 then set two;
```

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/65287/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p08a4x7h9mkwqvn16jg3xqwfxful.htm

Read  - **The Execution Phase** -
Pointer 5

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/basess/58133/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001290590.htm

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000961108.htm

Comment: Okay I got it . SAS is not going to reset a variable value to missing UNLESS it is about to read in a new record . Thank you

Comment: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/65287/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p08a4x7h9mkwqvn16jg3xqwfxful.htm

Comment: (Comments relevant to previous version of answer removed.)

Answer (score 1):

SAS sets a flag for each variable in the PDV, which specifies what will happen to it when the data step returns to the beginning of the loop.  This flag indicates that either a variable will be reset to missing, or it will not be reset to missing (and will retain is current value).

By default, this flag indicates that a variable should be reset.  This flag usually is set to 'retain value' in one of two ways.

- First, if a variable is present in a RETAIN statement, or has the SUM operator used with it on the left side (`x+1;`), the flag is set for that variable.
- Second, if a variable is present on a `set`, `merge`, 'modify', or `update` statement, the flag is set for that variable.

In this case, your variable `z` is present on a `set` statement, so it is automatically retained.

Here's another good example of this working.

```
data test1;
do x=1 to 5;
  y=2;
  output;
end;
run;

data test2;
  do x=6 to 10;
    output;
  end;
run;

data test3;
  set test1 test2;
  if x=7 then y=4;
run;
```

Here, `y` would be set to missing after the last record of `test1` is read; that's because at the end of a by group or dataset, it sets all variables to missing *once*.  However, `y` is still automatically retained; that flag isn't something that can change.  So when I set `y=4;` on the `x=7` record, that 4 is retained all the way throughout.  So `x=6` has a missing `y` but `x=7` through `x=10` have `y=4`.

*But wait*, you say.  My variables `x` and `y` are also present on a `set` statement, and they're not automatically retained.  They get re-set each time the data step reads from the dataset.

Nope.  They get set to a new value, yes: but they're never set to missing.  This has special relevance in a few cases: many to one merges, which basically work like the above, but with `by` groups: the `one` record is merged to all of the `many`, not because it is read in multiple times, but because it is read in once *and then not re-set to missing* (ie, is retained).  This is why a many to one merge is a bit dangerous if you're not aware of this:

```
data test1;
  do x=1 to 5;
    z=0;
    output;
  end;
run;

data test2;
  do x=1 to 5;
    do y=1 to 3;
      output;
    end;
  end;
run;

data testMerge;
  merge test1 test2;
  by x;
  if y=2 then z=1;
run;
```

Notice that `z=1` is true for `y=2` **and** for `y=3` records, even though I didn't ask for that!  Oops!  That's because `z` was read in from `test1` once for the first of each `x` by group record, and then not re-read after that - just retained.